# Jenkins "java.io.IOException: Failed to validate a server certificate" error trying to connect Windows build node to Ubuntu controller over websocket

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

I have been tasked with converting our Jenkins build environment to HTTPS.  In doing so, our Windows build nodes cannot connect to the Ubuntu controller over HTTPS.  We're getting the error:

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Our controller is serving HTTPS appropriately for the GUI, however, the build nodes cannot connect.  I've enabled websocket for the node.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried changing the java connection strings to no avail.

Comment: Your title should mention the real exception, as you did in your question. Duplicate.